# Is this data random or means something?

Tags: linux, crash, crash-reports, crash-dumps

[image]

If you look at the screen it seems to output something from an assembly program. This is what my Linux was trying to tell me when it didn't want to boot. Is it possible to understand or is it just random junk?

I don't really need to fix this problem since it is old but I am curious as to whether this is random junk or if a knowledgable person can understand something from the data shown.

Comment: This guy seems to have the same thing http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=7857&hilit=gfxgrub Other than err 8, it seems to be random junk.

Comment: Lots of similar screens when people tried to boot with bad CDs/DVDs: [1](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/24508), [2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=986678), [3, german](http://www.linux-club.de/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=94161), [4, italian](http://www.hwupgrade.it/forum/archive/index.php/t-1687988.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look through the link yhyrcanus gave, but to me it looks like it's some sort of BIOS error. The table is (I think) a dump of the data and code segments. 'ip' would be the instruction pointer, perhaps? Good luck.